# Переобработка контента js после AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, material-design

Всем привет.

Юзаю MDL(getmdl.io), в частности идёт работа с таблицей.
Цель - подгрузить AJAXом таблицу с возможностью выбора каждой из позиций. Чекбоксы в этой таблице делаются js библиотекой MDL. 
Проблема:
при таком решении JS не обрабатывает таблицу, то есть применяются только стили, без чекбоксов. С подгружаемым кодом проблем нет, если его вставлять сразу в исходную страницу галочки работают.
По идее, надо как-то заставить переобработься javascriptом новый кусок кода, полученный с ajax. 
Как решить данную проблему?
Заранее спасибо

```js
function ShowGoods(distr) {
  console.log(distr);
  if (distr.classList.contains('checked'))
    distr.classList.remove('checked');
  else {
    $.ajax({
      url: '/core/interface/goods/showdistr.php',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'html',
      data: {
        distributor: distr.value,
        city: 'spb'
      },
      success: function(responce) {
        $('#add-goods').html(responce);
      },
      error: function() {
        return 0;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:regular,bold,italic,thin,light,bolditalic,black,medium&amp;lang=en">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.indigo-pink.min.css">

<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Material</th>
      <th>Quantity</th>
      <th>Unit price</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id='add-goods'>
   <!-- рабочий код --> 
   <tr>
      <td class="mdl-data-table__cell--numeric">1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<!-- пример подгружаемого кода: 
  <tr>
     <td class=\"mdl-data-table__cell--numeric\">1</td>
     <td>2</td>
     <td>3</td>
  </tr>
-->
```

Comment: вот это `Чекбоксы в этой таблице делаются js библиотекой MDL` надо делать после того как ajax-результат аппендится на страницу.

Comment: каким образом? таблица появляется после какого-то действия пользователя. Более того, опытно установлено что если две строки таблицы на странице уже есть(нормальные), то третья(с ajaxа) уже будет без галочки...
Я знаю какая библиотека отвечает за это. Так как заставить её "сделать галочки"?

Comment: @Jean-Claude Поясню, может неправильно сформулировал. Галочки формируются фрэймворком, с моеё стороны для их появления добавляется только класс "mdl-data-table--selectable".

Comment: я и говорю, вы добавляете этот класс - js инициализируется и формирует галочки, после подзагрузки ajax'ом данных, он не понимает, что надо опять формировать галки - дайте команду js-скрипту на формирование новых галочек, то есть инициализировать скрипт повторно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Прочите внимательно секцию **Use MDL on dynamic websites** https://getmdl.io/started/index.html и особенно на строчку `componentHandler.upgradeElement(button);` - именно это вам и надо сделать после успешного ajax-запроса.

```
<div id="container"/>
<script>
  var button = document.createElement('button');
  var textNode = document.createTextNode('Click Me!');
  button.appendChild(textNode);
  button.className = 'mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect';
  componentHandler.upgradeElement(button);
  document.getElementById('container').appendChild(button);
</script>
```

Пример скрипта добавляющего кнопку и соотвественно mdl-апгрейд согласно инструкции

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-lite/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/material-design-lite/1.1.3/material.min.css">
  <style>
    body {
      padding: 50px;
    }
    button {
      margin: 0 5px !important;
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $('#add').on('click', function() {
        $('body').append('<button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">Button</button>');
        componentHandler.upgradeElement($('button').last().get(0));
      });
    });
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <input type="button" value="Добавить галку" id="add">

  <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--accent">Button</button>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! В след раз буду внимательнее курить мануалы ...

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо ответившим, уточню после курения github google:
https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/wiki/Deprecations#automatic-selection-checkboxes
официальное решение этого вопроса
Уточню: галочки добавляем руками, а после делаем

```
componentHandler.upgradeDom();
```

Возможно есть более рациональные пути решения, если найду - дополню